# Issues with joining 3D scanned OBJs

Tags: mesh, texturing, import, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

We work with another program to first create a human head with particular facial features, then we try to join it with another scanned mesh (the human body) in Blender. Both are in obj format.

The problem is when we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, it mixes all the colors and one of the meshes loses its colors by doing this. Is there another way to join the head and the body without losing the real color of both meshes?

This is the result of the joining in Blender software and the other is obj obtained from the 3d scanner directly, and I need to preserve the colors of the face and the body individually

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are those colors applied to the mesh? Texture? Vertex Colors? Materials? Joining them should have no effect. Could you post some screenshots of the before and after results?

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for replying. I have a 3d sense scanner, thats how i got texture for half of the mesh, the other half come from another software of reconstruction of faces that allows me to export in obj , ply and others. Because i have to join them i use blender with ctrl+J but it loses our own colors ( independent) and it result with the color of the mesh I obtain by the software in obj. If you speak spanish please tell me.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Any chance we could look at any example file where the issues happen? Could you please edit your question and upload as **simplified file** as possible [file reproducing the problem](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) with **all textures and relevant data packed**?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos as u can see below when i import the obj in blender it seems like all the textures are mixed together in disorder and i can not edit it to transform it in solid for printing texturized in addecuately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a procedure for baking the color from a 3D scan to a UV map in Blender: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/03/24/RealSense-3D-scan-Vertex-Color-to-UV-Map-Blender

Follow this process for both meshes (the head then the body). Then try to join them. If the textures are baked and applied via a UV map, both colors should remain when you join the meshes. [image]

Comment: this is the result of the joining in blender software and the other is obj obtaining from the 3d scanner directly and I need to preserve the colors of the face and the body individually